# Static integers

Tags: c++, static, scope

I was wondering how static worked. Here is an example:

```
void count()
{
    static int x = 1;
    cout << "Static: " << x << endl;
    x++;

    return;
}

int main()
{
    //Static variable test
    cout << endl;
    count();
    count();
}
```

This program gives an output of "1 and 2". But I was wondering when the function "count" is called for the second time, why isn't the "static int x = 1" line executed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a language rule; the initialization of a `static` variable is only performed once.

Note that this is different from

```
static int x;
x = 1;
```

which would reset `x` to 1 in every call.

Answer (score 2):

Static local vars are sort of like globals except that the compiler only lets that one function access it.  All statically-allocated objects (builtin or user-defined types), including static member variables of structs/classes, are initialized once by the system before it calls your main() function.  You can use this characteristic to your advantage (or get some curious behavior if you don't know what's going on) by making global (or static file-scope) instances of a class, and in the class constructor, do something interesting.  That code will run before main() starts.

BUT.... You have to be careful doing that.  There is no standard way of forcing the order of these initialized objects, so if one depends on another being already initialized, what "works fine" one day may start "not working fine" when you change compilers or compiler options, or add/remove source files, etc.

Comment: What kind of interesting things can you do exactly?

Comment: We use that characteristic to add unit tests to a global array of unit tests to run.  We use a macro called TESTCASE(test_name) that creates a global variable named test_name##_XXXX (I don't remember what XXXX is, but the ## adds the _XXXX to the text "test name" and makes it all one identifier).  The global variable is of a type whose constructor simply adds a function pointer to the following function to a global array for later execution.  Then the macro ends by creating the signature for the test function itself, and after that, you add the curly-brace and begin the test function's code.

Comment: ...that way you don't have to make a header file declaring the existence of your unit test function, and then go to some main "test case executor" file & add your new function to an ever-growing list of tests to run, which would spread it out over three files.  This way the whole unit test is isolated to just a few lines of a single file, and it's also easy to disable right there at the source without going to a separate file to comment it out.

Comment: I also use that characteristic from time-to-time when I want a global array of something that has to be computed at run-time for whatever reason or other, and I don't want to burden the application with needing to call an "init" method to initialize the array.  So I make a class constructor do it & make a single global instance of the class.  Generally this isn't a recommended way of building a system, but it's handy from time-to-time.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the rules say. You can think of the `static` line as being executed only the first time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

It is. Otherwise you couldn't read the value of `x` at all. It does not, however, set the value of `x` if it has already been created.